# How to use FILTER function with wildcard?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use the Google Sheets FILTER function to filter for string that contains the word 'groups'.

The code I'm using is this:

```
=filter(A2:C2262,B2:B2262="*"&"groups"&"*")
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work as the error message I receive is "No matches are found in FILTER evaluation."

I've attached a screenshot to show the table I'm working with.

How do I make this work?

[image: screenshot of what I'm trying to do]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(A:A, SEARCH("*group*", A:A))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I just wish I knew why mine doesn't.

Comment: Your version does not work because no value exactly equals "*group*" (note that you don't need to concatenate 3 strings). @player0 added the SEARCH function, which will return a non-zero value if it finds "group" anywhere and thus, consider a row.