# How to use wildcards with the FILTER function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to use the Filter function with wildcards, as shown below. I have viewed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62973592/how-to-use-filter-function-with-wildcard) (although it pertains to Google Sheets) and tried it but I failed. How can i make it work?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formula is pretty close to working. What makes it fail is that `SEARCH` returns `#VALUE` when it does not find `"Apple"` in `Banner C`. Just wrap your `SEARCH` in an `IFERROR`:

```
=FILTER(D7:E9,IFERROR(SEARCH("Apple",D7:D9),0))
```

**Edit**

As mentioned by @Ben Knight, there is no need for wildcards here, since you are searching for a single word. `"Apple"` work the same as `"*Apple*"`. If you wanted to find `Apple(whatever)Cucumber` in `Apple Banana Cucumber`, you would search for `"Apple*Cucumber"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do without the IFERROR by using an ARRAYFORMULA+ISNUMBER+SEARCH combination:

```
=filter(D7:E9,arrayformula(isnumber(search("Apple",D7:D9,1)))=true)
```

No need to use wildcards either; just word "Apple" itself will be enough.

Comment: OP is using Excel; arrayformula is specific to Google Sheets - interesting nonetheless!

Comment: @Excelosaurus In Excel, you can just use `=FILTER(D7:E9,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Apple",D7:D9,1)))`